# how to add new font to Xcode 3.2?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2, xcode3.2, uifont

please tell me how to add new font to iphone xcode3.2.

Comment: Updated my answer with UIAppFonts info!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This functionality isn't built into UILabel/UIFont in iOS < 3.2. But there is a third-party solution you can use: [FontLabel](https://web.archive.org/web/20100525133211/http://github.com:80/zynga/FontLabel/)

In iOS 3.2+, there's the [UIAppFonts plist key](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html)!

Just do this before using it: add your font file (such as `myfont.ttf`) to your project, then edit the Info.plist like so:

[image: info.plist]

Comment: but i want to use UIAppFonts you have any idea how to use way

Comment: i use this approach but when i load font using below code

UIFont *myF = [UIFont fontWithName:@"my font name" size:12];


myF is return null;

Comment: I would think that the name is wrong or the file isn't getting included in the project. There's a good post about this here: http://www.perfectline.co.uk/blog/uiappfonts-custom-fonts-with-the-iphoneipad-3-2-sdk

Comment: Hello! For me it doesn't work it crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i want to retrieve the fontfamilynames. I already posted a questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727710/adding-a-uifont-and-looking-for-the-fontfamily-crashes-with-exc-bad-access). Could you tell me, what i'm doing wrong? Thx

Answer (score 2):

The above methods worked for me in xcode 3.2!  Thanks!:

step 1: drag your font into your project (prob a good idea to not have spaces in the font name)
step 2: add a row to your info.plist file like shown above to enter your font.
step 3: in, viewDidLoad() or wherever you are setting your label, enter code:

```
 UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"secondbreakfast" size:40];
 myLabel.font = myFont;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the following way:

1. Add the font type to the Xcode : Under the XIB, go the font setting -> manage font
2. Add the font to the label:

   UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myfont" size:12];
   label.font = myFont;

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

But in xcode 5

1. Go to `xcode preferences` -> `Fonts and colors`.
2. Then click on `T` button in the `textField` of Font.

A list of all colors open then click on `setting button` in bottom left corner and go to `manage fonts`

Here select `All fonts` and then add your own `ttf file` by clicking on `plus button`
and your Font will be added.